# Async Method does not return control back to caller

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Control is returned back to main method, before `UploadToServer` executes completely. Should I remove `Task.Run()` from `UploadToServer` or do a `WaitAll` explicitly?

```
public class Uploader
{
    async public Task<int> Upload(int i)
    {
        int incremented = 0;
        var t = UploadToServer(i);
        if (t != null)
        {
            incremented = await t;
        }
        return incremented;
    }

    async private Task<int> UploadToServer(int i)
    {
        int incremented = 0;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Console.ReadLine();
            //Actual upload operation
            incremented = i + 1;
        });
        return incremented;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uploader upl = new Uploader();
        var res = upl.Upload(10).Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this real code? what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Well, duh, that's how `await` works. And using `Task.Run` for asynchronous I/O operation is a bad idea anyway. What's your actual problem?

Comment: @Luaan, I have used `.Result` that is a blocking call to async method to fetch the result. What about that?

Comment: That still means the control goes back to the `Main` method - you're just waiting for the task to complete there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `await` on `async` methods, the control is yielded back to the caller. What you're experiencing is proper `async` behavior.

If you dont want the method to return while the operation is executing, execute it **synchronously**.
If what you're attempting to do is I/O bound work (like upload something to a server), dont use `Task.Run`, as I/O bound is naturally exposed with async endpoints, eliminating the need for unnecessary threads in the process. Look at [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) as an example which exposes a bunch of `XXXAsync` methods.

Comment: When I am doing database update operation, should I use async?

Comment: I would highly recommend so. That of course depends on your DB provider supplying an `async` endpoint. In case you're using `Entity Framework` or `ADO.NET`, those already do have those.

Comment: I am using EntityFramework, but we have wrapped EF code into UnitOfWork, that does not expose async. :-(

Comment: There is no need to wrap EF in `UnitOfWork`, DBContext does exactly that. What you can do is add methods to your unit of work which add the `async` api exposed by EF

Comment: When control is returned to the caller, does the same thread get used by caller?

Comment: @variable Not necessarily, it depends on the SynchronizationContext at scope that was captured for the async call.

Comment: Synchronization context stores the environment context. Does it also control which thread will run?

Comment: @variable https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/06/24/what-is-synchronizationcontext/

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
private Task<int> UploadToServer(int i)
{
    int incremented = 0;
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Console.ReadLine();
        //Actual upload operation
        return incremented = i + 1;
    });
}
```

or in this way

```
private async Task<int> UploadToServer(int i)
{
     return await Task.Run(() => DoSomething(i)).Wait();
}

private int DoSomething(int i)
{
    //Console.ReadLine();
    //Actual upload operation
     return i+1;
}
```

Note that these examples aren't particularly useful methods. 
considers that the background thread should live its own life.

In your case I suppose that maybe you can use some async methods of the `HttpClient` class of the framework

Example

```
private async Task<int> GetWebPageHtmlSizeAsync()
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var html = await client.GetAsync("http://www.test.com/");
  return html.Length;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've tested this code and it worked

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Uploader upl = new Uploader();
     var res = upl.Upload(10).Result;
}


public class Uploader 
{
    async public Task<int> Upload(int i)
    {
        int incremented = 0;
        var t = UploadToServer(i);
        if (t != null)
        {
            incremented = await t;
        }
        return incremented;
    }

    private async Task<int> UploadToServer(int i)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => DoSomething(i));
    }

    private int DoSomething(int i)
    {
        //Console.ReadLine();
        //Actual upload operation
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return i + 1;
    }
}
```

main program waits 2 seconds before receive the right value and the control back.

Have a look at this [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) article that explains when and how you should use asynchronous methods. In your specific example you aren't getting advantages from task.run. I have only provided to you one working example with your code.

Comment: He's not only trying to expose async over sync, he's doing it for IO bound work. No need for `Task.Run` at all here.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. In fact I have wrote that isn't useful. I will complete my answer

Comment: `var result = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething(i));` Can't convert void to a return type.

Comment: @faby, thanks but I tried your code. but before `return Task.Run(()` returns controls is already returned back to caller.

Comment: @Abhijeet add .Wait() after task.run and let me know

Comment: Already tried that: before posting question. Same behaviour, when I step into Task.Run() & while still it is executing. Control had returned back to the caller!

Comment: I've tested my code and it worked. I've edited the answer. Let me Know

Comment: Its funny, as you reference an article in your answer which explicitly says *"dont wrap sync methods with `Task.Run`"*, and yet your answer contains code that does.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you're right. I've written that this solution isn't useful